# Cordova CLI Command

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-cli

Iam new to phonegap/cordova and got a general question.
Yesterday I created a test app and today i wanted to test it on my device. First i started local server with "cordova serve android" and then deployed it on m,y device via "cordova run android --device". Everything worked but my testapp www directory got replaced with cordova default direcotry. May it be that commands like "cordova run android --device" or "cordova serve android" overrides the existing www direcotry in my project folder and replace it with default one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your www folder inside platform folder got replaced? or the folder just inside your project got replaced?

You need to put your code in this folder `yourprojectnamedirectory->www` and after you provide this command `cordova run android`, that code will be posted inside all platform folders automatically and run on the device. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: Oh Okay! I worked in myproject/platforms/android/assets/www and everytime I ran the command it got replaced with myproject/www... makes sense! Thank you for your fast answer!